# Firebase Cloud Functions raise time limit

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have written a cloud function for Firebase that is a https callable and is supposed to delete all files inside a folder. It looks like so:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const {Storage} = require("@google-cloud/storage");
const storage = new Storage({keyFilename: "myserviceaccount.json"});
const fileBucket = "myfilebucket";


    exports.deleteFolder = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "unauthenticated",
        "only authenticated users can add requests"
    );
  }
 
  const bucket = storage.bucket(fileBucket);
  return bucket.deleteFiles({
    prefix: `${data.folderName}`,
  }, function(err:any) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
      console.log(`All the Firebase Storage files in users/${data.folderName}/ have been deleted`);
    }
  });
});
```

That works fine. But my folders sometimes hold quite a lot documents, so the standard time limit of 60s that I get when deploying this function is sometimes not enough to delete all files inside the folder. So I would like to raise the time limit for computation to 540s witch is according to [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas) the maximum computation time I can get. But I cannot find a possibility to do so.

How do I raise the time limit for a single https callable function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation), you need to do as follows:

```
const runtimeOpts = {
        timeoutSeconds: 540
      }


exports.deleteFolder = functions
                        .runWith(runtimeOpts)
                        .https
                        .onCall(async (data, context) => {...});
```

---

Note that you can also configure this value via the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions) (not the Firebase Console).

In the Google Cloud Console , select your Firebase project, select the "Cloud Functions" vertical menu item, click on the Function name, then click on the "Edit" Button. Then click on the "VARIABLEs, .... " section title as shown below and adjust the Timeout value in the corresponding field.

[image]